# Volley Post String and get JSONArray

Tags: android, json, android-volley

so i have an little issue on my Code. I wan't to open a secret file on my server, so for that i have to send a POST String. In my case it is a name of a mysql tabel. And after that, the php code search for this tabel and give me a look inside there. But i don't have an idea why it don't work. It's a school project and the result will be rated.

I use this code in Android Studio
`requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());`

```
    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, showURL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            try {
                JSONArray products = response.getJSONOArray("products");

                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject product = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    String article = product.getString("article");
                    //String user = product.getString("user");

                    items.add(article);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // handle errors here
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {   // send parameters here
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("table", "products");
            // add other parameters
            return params;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(request);

}`
```

Have anyone an idea how it works? Thank you for your help :D